# Rails - Update attributes without remove old items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Does anybody know, has RoR method to update attributes for model without remove previous items ?

For example, user has a lot of locations and organizations. 
params = {location_ids: [1,2,3], organization_ids: [1,2,3]}

```
user = User.first
user.location_ids --> [3,4,5]
user.organization_ids --> [3,4,5]
user.update(params) --> in this case user will have location_ids as [1,2,3], and organization_ids as [1,2,3]

user.<some_method>(params) --> user has location_ids as [1,2,3,4,5] and organization_ids as [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Or maybe, can you propose some special method like update ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
params[:location_ids] = (user.location_ids + params[:location_ids]).uniq
params[:organization_ids] = (user.organization_ids + params[:organization_ids]).uniq
user.update_attributes(params)
```

`.uniq` will ensure that there are no duplicates.